# How does MySQL CONCAT IFNULL work with more than two values?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, ifnull

I need to `CONCAT` two fields, if they both exist and add parentheses around the second field.  Otherwise I just need to list the first field.

Here's the simple version:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(name,' (',nickname,')') as name FROM user;
```

As long as name and nickname both exist you should get results like:

```
1 | Adam (Alpha Dog)
2 | Bob (Bobby)
3 | Charles (Charlie)
```

But if there is no nickname it just skips the whole thing as `null`.  For example: id `4`, name `Doug`, nickname `null` gives the result:

```
4 | null
```

What I'd like to see is it to list just the name... like this:

```
4 | Doug
```

So I started looking at `CONCAT` `IFNULL`.  But I'm having a hard time getting it right.  Can you help?

Here are a few examples of things I've tried:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(IFNULL(name, ' (', nickname, ')', name) as name FROM user;
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, IFNULL(' (', nickname, ')')) as name FROM user;
```

Comment: IFNULL( CONCAT( '(', nickname, ')' ), '' )

Comment: Something to point out that threw me off at first. When nickname is null then CONCAT('(',nickname,')') will also return null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use CONCAT_WS which skips null strings:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(' ', name, concat('(',nickname,')')) as name FROM user;
```

Comment: if nickname is NULL you will get NULL as result

Comment: If you'd need to use `CONCAT` instead of `CONCAT_WS` for any reason, you can do a `COALESCE(column, '')` wrapper around each nullable column, which is a more elegant way than the mentioned `CASE` or `IF` solutions from below.

Comment: Note that the first argument in CONCAT_WS is a separator

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate the parens and the `nickname`, and then use the `IFNULL` to check to see if the result of that expression is NULL.

If it's null, replace the NULL with an empty string, and then concatenate that expression to the `name` column.

```
SELECT id
     , CONCAT(name,IFNULL(CONCAT(' (',nickname,')'),'')) AS name
  FROM user
```

NOTE: The IFNULL function is shorthand for:

```
IF(expr1 IS NULL,expr2,expr1)
```

or the ANSI equivalent:

```
CASE WHEN expr1 IS NULL THEN expr2 ELSE expr1 END
```

There are other approaches that will work just as well. But they all basically need to do the same thing: check if nickname is NULL, and then conditionally include the parens and the nickname, or an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, concat(name , if(nickname is not null, concat(' (', nickname, ')'), '')) as name FROM user;
```

Comment: In my case i need to check for empty string, not null so my code is ```if(nickname != '')```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT id, 
  case 
    when nickname is not null 
    then CONCAT(name,' (',nickname,')')
    else name end as name 
FROM user;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c671/3)

Or:

```
SELECT id, 
  concat(name, if(nickname is not null, concat(' (',nickname,')'), '')) as name
FROM user;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c671/10)

Both give the same result:

```
| ID |              NAME |
--------------------------
|  1 |  Adam (Alpha Dog) |
|  2 |       Bob (Bobby) |
|  3 | Charles (Charlie) |
|  4 |              Doug |
```